# GPG tutorial for beginners

Tags: security, encryption, gnupg

Where can I find a good tutorial on using GPG for the absolute beginner?

Every time I see someone say that you should send public communications using encryption, GPG comes up; where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search in Google for the words "GPG for beginners" turned up a number of results, with this one coming up first:

Beginner's Guide to GnuPG by Nat Queen
  http://www.queen.clara.net/pgp/art3.html

You didn't mention which Operating System you're using, so I'll assume Unix/Linux since GPG seems to be more common among users working in these environments.  Here's a link for that Google search:

Google Search Results:  gpg for beginners
  http://www.google.com/search?q=gpg+for+beginners

If that first guide doesn't provide you with the information you need, hopefully the other search results, some of which are YouTube videos, can lead you to something that will.